# Stuck calling a onclick function

Tags: javascript

I have been banging my head on this for a while now...

```
medReviewCtrl = "<form name=\"medsreviewedform\"> \
    <input type=\"button\" class=\"medsreviewedclass\" name=\"medsreviewedname\" \
    id=\"medsreviewedid\" value=\"7 minutes ago\" onclick=\"ChangeButtonText(this)\" \
    </form>";

function ChangeButtonText(button){
    document.getElementById("medsreviewedid").value="Value has changed";
}​
```

I have a js file where I create a dynammic div of which this button is part of it. The button displays fine and but when I try to call this function I get Object Expected. If I do it like this it works;

```
onclick=\"this.value=this.value==this.defaultValue?'Less than a minute ago':this.defaultValue;\" />";
```

Ultimately the objective the default value will be derived from a time value (1 week ago) and onclick will write to a value to the database and the buttons value will be something like less than a minute ago. I have everything else but I just cannot figure out how to change the value.

I have tried the code is jsFiddle and it works there but not in my example. http://jsfiddle.net/hPQP9/61/

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Share link to said jsFiddle example.

Comment: i/m not sure why u have backslash before " there is no need for it and it can cause some problems...

Comment: Could you please provide the link to jsFiddle?

Comment: We need a jsFiddle that doesn't work, how do you insert the form into html?

Answer (score 0):

Try this, I prefer using a single quote for html code:

```
medReviewCtrl = '<form name="medsreviewedform"> \
<input type="button" class="medsreviewedclass" name="medsreviewedname" \
id="medsreviewedid" value="7 minutes ago" onclick="ChangeButtonText(this)"> \
</form>';
```

Comment: Appreciate that but it still fails.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, interesting; Javascript vs Jquery...

```
    $(function(){
    $("#medsreviewedid").click(function(){
        alert('hi');
    });
});

medReviewCtrl = '<form name="medsreviewedform"> \
    <input type="button" class="medsreviewedclass" name="medsreviewedname" \
    id="medsreviewedid" value="7 minutes ago"></form>';
```

Works fine!